# Trying to find the log of a number but it is not working for some reason

Tags: c++, recursion

I am trying to write a program that solves a log function. As a start, I am only making it so that it can calculate logs with whole number answers (for example, log 6 of 36 = 2). I took the recursion route and logically, it seems very doable, when trying to implement it, it is not working. I am not getting any syntax errors, but what is happening is I am getting "Unhandled Exception" errors which I believe is because of the recursion route I took (infinite loop for some reason?). Hopefully that was enough info for an answer, thanks!

```
int counter = 1;

void checkifDone(int initial, int base, int exponent); 

int main() {
    checkifDone(6, 6, 7776);
    
}
void checkifDone(int initial, int base, int exponent) {
    
    base = initial * base; 
    counter++;
    if (base < exponent) {
        checkifDone(initial, base, exponent);
    }
    else if (base == exponent) {
        
        cout << "Answer is " << counter << endl;
    }
    else 
        cout << "not a whole number answer" << endl;
    
}
```

Comment: Trace through the path of what happens if `exponent` isn't a power of `base`. Hint: `if(base != exponent)` is not the same as `if(base < exponent)`. There's a lot else that's incorrect with this code but that'll cause the infinite loop.

Comment: should be base < exponent. Nice attempt, failure is more valuable than success when you are learning :)
Make sure you are using an editor with a good debugger so you don't have to resort to SO for these sorts of problems. I recommend CLion for what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks bro how can I add a comment with my code highlighted? I looked at the help page I still cant figure it out, how can I do this? I have a quick question about my code still. What is SO?

Comment: SO is Stack Overflow, the site we're on. Single backticks will perform `inline highlighting`, although it may make more sense as an edit to your question than as a comment.

Comment: I am absolutely clueless haha... Well, I just edited my code and it works just fine, but I have a question about its efficiency. Even though I am not the best programmer, I do know that global variables are not the best to have in your program- like ```int counter = 1``` (or at least good to avoid), can I easily avoid doing so in this specific program? I've always had trouble with this idea, would appreciate a suggestion. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

This causes recursion as long as `base != exponent`. The `else` branch is never invoked (since `if` and `else if` cover all possibilities).

Easier would be to use a while loop and check for less-than:

```
void checkifDone(int base, int exponent) {
   int count = 0;
   int curr = 1;
   while (base < exponent) {
      curr *= base;
      ++count;
   }
   if (curr == exponent) {
      std::cout << "Answer is " << count << std::endl;
   } else {
      std::cout << "not a perfect log" << std::endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: Note that this will incorrectly conclude that `8` isn't a power of `2`.

Comment: Hey man thanks for answering, I thought about it for a bit thoroughly and I finally got it!! While I didn't use your guys' solution, it kind of opened up my thinking more. By the way Kostas, (this is my fault btw) the base = base * base section is not valid for this reason: The base will start multiplying by itself, not the initial base that the user gave, here is the updated code I wrote, again though, thanks for your help!

Comment: I am having trouble marking the code in a comment haha sorry man let me figure this out...

Comment: I just edited my actual code if you are interested in what I came up with, thanks again for your help!

Comment: Looks good! This should be compiled to a loop, so passing the extra parameter shouldn't add overhead either.

Comment: It always takes a long time when you start programming. It definitely comes with experience but that's not enough imo. You have to constantly strive to write code you are proud with and look for improvements.

Comment: Alright thanks for the answers, how can I close this question (if that is possible)?

Comment: You don't need to. If you accept answer likely no one will look at this question again